# R: How to partially overlap maps using layout()

Tags: r, maps

I have three maps of the same region, in different years. I wanna plot them side by side, very close to each other. I know how to use the layout() function to do that, but they keep far from each other. This is what I'm getting:

[image: maps too far from each other]

This is what I want:

[image: maps closer to each other]

I need some sort of overlapping of the cells in the matrix passed to layout() function. Or shifting the axis of the plot() function. But I couldn't find anything like these. Any help, please?

Comment: In what package is the `display` function? What's the format of you spatial data. **maps** files? `SpatialPolygons`? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, it is layout() function (graphics package). I edited above. My data is in ESRI shapefile (.shp).

Comment: I read the shapefile using rgdal readOGR()

Comment: ...thus my data is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Comment: One option I might pursue would be to laterally shift two of the `SpatialPolygons` objects (perhaps using `maptools::elide(SP, shift=(xshift, 0))`) and then `rbind` them together (1st making sure that they've each been given unique ID's). The other option would be, using the **grid** and perhaps **gridBase** package, to create three partially overlapping viewports and plot the three maps into those. Neither of those are real easy solutions, but they're the best I can think of. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, Josh! It seems much easier to just shift them in Paint hehehe! But ok, I'll try it someday when I have free time. Now I've already finished the maps that naive way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose how your maps should be spaced *without* `layout()`. `par(new=TRUE)`and `par(plt=...)` are the keys.
You did a pretty chart ! Still, given the data plotted, I would not have made a continuous color bar.

```
library("maps")

par(list(mar=c(0,0,4,0), bg="black"))
plot(0:1, 0:1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
title("Trois cartes de France se chevauchant", col.main="white")

# Random colors to highlight the overlapping.
set.seed(13)

par(list(new=TRUE, plt=c(.6, 1, .1, .9)))
plot(map("france", plot=FALSE), type="l", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", col=sample(c("white", "blue", "red"), 1))
par(list(new=TRUE, plt=c(.3, .7, .1, .9)))
plot(map("france", plot=FALSE), type="l", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", col=sample(c("white", "blue", "red"), 1))
par(list(new=TRUE, plt=c(0, .4, .1, .9)))
plot(map("france", plot=FALSE), type="l", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", col=sample(c("white", "blue", "red"), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: gonna try it! Thank you!